# Parsley.js validate parts of form based on selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

Probably most easily explained via this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shanomurphy/dL688o9j/

I want to show/hide parts of a form based on what radio button is selected. When a radio button is checked I show some extra form fields and hide others. I only want Parsley.js to validate the shown fields.

I'm running into problems when the selected radio button is changed and parsley validation has already been run.

```js
// Vars
var drinks_fields = $('#drinks');
var food_fields   = $('#food');
    
// Hide fields until needed
drinks_fields.hide();
food_fields.hide();

$("input[name=choice]").on('click', function() {

    if ( $(this).val() == 'Drinks' ) {
        
        // Show drinks hide food
        drinks_fields.show();
        food_fields.hide();
        
        // Update required
        $("input[name=drinks]").prop('required',true);
        $("input[name=food]").prop('required',false);
        
    } else if ( $(this).val() == 'Food' ) {
        
        // Show food hide drinks
        food_fields.show();
        drinks_fields.hide();
        
        // Update required
        $("input[name=food]").prop('required',true);
        $("input[name=drinks]").prop('required',false);
    
    }
    
});
```

```html
<form data-parsley-validate="true">
    
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Choice</legend>
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Drinks" required data-parsley-error-message="Choose drinks or food"/>Drinks
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Food"/>Food
   </fieldset>
    
   <fieldset id="drinks">
       <legend>Drinks</legend>
       <input type="checkbox" name="drinks" data-parsley-mincheck="2" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-error-message="Choose min 2 drinks"/>Water
       <input type="checkbox" name="drinks"/>Pepsi
       <input type="checkbox" name="drinks"/>Orange Juice
   </fieldset>
    
   <fieldset id="food">
       <legend>Food</legend>
       <input type="checkbox" name="food" data-parsley-mincheck="2" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-error-message="Choose min 2 foods"/>Cake
       <input type="checkbox" name="food"/>Hotdog
       <input type="checkbox" name="food"/>Pizza
   </fieldset>
       
   <button type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

After showing / hiding the fields, you need to re-bind Parlsey.

Something like this:

```
$("input[name=choice]").on('click', function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == 'Drinks' ) {
        // your code
    } else if ( $(this).val() == 'Food' ) {
        // your code
    }

    $("form").parsley().destroy();

    $("form").parsley();
});
```

Alternatively, you can destroy the ParsleyField object for the fields you hide and create a ParsleyField object for the fields that are displayed, like this:

```
$("input[name=choice]").on('click', function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == 'Drinks' ) {
        // Show drinks hide food
        drinks_fields.show();
        drinks_fields.parsley();
        food_fields.hide();
        food_fields.parsley().destroy();
        // Update required
        $("input[name=drinks]").prop('required',true);
        $("input[name=food]").prop('required',false);
    } else if ( $(this).val() == 'Food' ) {
        // Show food hide drinks
        food_fields.show();
        food_fields.parsley();
        drinks_fields.hide();
        drinks_fields.parsley().destroy();
        // Update required
        $("input[name=food]").prop('required',true);
        $("input[name=drinks]").prop('required',false);
    }  
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but I think parlsey v2 is meant to avoid that kind of things.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune As they say, this is not a bug, it's a feature : ) The thing is, when you apply parsley to a form (in this case, through `data-parsley-validate="true"`), Parsley will create a `ParsleyForm` object and a `ParsleyField` to each field (that are not excluded from the config). If, on-the-fly, you hide or display a field, the ParsleyField either remains or doesn't exist at all. This is why you need to destroy parsley and re-bind it, so it destroys the existing objects and create new ones.

Comment: There is an alternative solution for this issue. That is destroy the `ParsleyField` object for the each hidden field and create the ParsleyField object for each shown fields. See the updated answer.

Comment: Right, but neither of these should be necessary. See my updated answer for the two bugs I found.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting example and great fiddle.

Now that 2.0.6 is released, your fiddle would work if you also changed the `data-parsley-mincheck` attribute accordingly. Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/mnrst3cc/3/) The error display isn't working properly though, not sure why.

Your question illustrated [a bug](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/pull/773) with removing a required field. It also illustrated [another bug](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/pull/776) with removing all constraints (which brought up some [flawed](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/pull/774) [tests](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/pull/775) too).

These bugs are fixed in 2.0.6.

There is another way to look at the issue though. Instead of changing the `required` attributes of your fields, you could simple exclude hidden inputs:

```
jQuery("form").parsley({ excluded: ":hidden" });
```

Complete [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/marcandre/mnrst3cc/2/). In this example, the error messages won't show though, I'm not sure why (I just started looking seriously at `parlsey` yesterday).

Comment: It seems that the ul.parsley-errors-list element that's supposed to contain the error messages is missing for all elements that were hidden when your validator instance was created. I just logged an issue for that, as this is clearly a bug -> https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/864